# LMG don't sum to model's R2

Tags: r, importance

I have a regression model and I want to determine the relative importance of the predictors. I used the package `relaimpo` in r.

The package says that 98.84% of the variance is explained by the model

```
Response variable: C 
Total response variance: 115.4857 
Analysis based on 161187 observations 

10 Regressors: 
I(VPT^(-0.66)) TPA S SD TPA:VPT S:SD TPA:SD TPA:S SD:VPT S:VPT 
Proportion of variance explained by model: 98.84%
```

I did not normalize the metrics.

```
Metrics are not normalized (rela=FALSE).
```

These are my relative importance metrics:

```
Relative importance metrics: 

                        lmg
I(VPT^(-0.66)) 0.2647988336
TPA            0.0776291924
S              0.0816760485
SD             0.2661375234
TPA:VPT        0.0779008229
S:SD           0.0036628215
TPA:SD         0.0002298444
TPA:S          0.0002684624
SD:VPT         0.0065747570
S:VPT          0.0114800491
```

They sum up `0.79`. Shouldn't they sum up to `0.9884`? If so, why don't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not include your R code I don't know your exact problem. One potential solution (based on your output) would be to change your model equation to include rela=TRUE. Example:

```
calc.relimp(regModel,type=c("lmg","last","first","pratt"),rela=TRUE)
```

If you post your R code I may be able to give you more details.

Comment: This should be posted rather as a comment then an answer since it is a question to OP.

Comment: A agree that this presently looks more like a comment. This may potentially be turned into an answer if you explain more fully how it relates to the question being asked.

Comment: I clarified my solution, I believe this will answer any issues in the comments above. Feel free to let me know if it does not.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question (even though the OP thinks so!). According to the manual "`rela` is a logical requesting relative importances summing to 100% (`rela=TRUE`). If `rela` is `FALSE` (default), some of the metrics sum to $R^2$ (`lmg`,[...]". So why doesn't LMG sum to the proportion of variance explained in this case when `rela=FALSE`? Something to do with having interactions in the model?

Answer (score 0):

if you read the Final remarks of reference article of the package in page 25, it is written : "As a further step, factors with interaction terms will require the procedure to be able to respect a pre-defined hierarchy, i.e., some orders of regressors (interaction before main effect) must be excluded from the possibilities. **This would also be a desirable extension of relaimpo**."

So, I interpret **package does not support interactions currently** and in future, its update hopefully will.